# How do I add extra warnings in Oasis?

Tags: ocaml, oasis

I have [this](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/blob/004f289d277fb859a48b572593c7e3980488c0bd/_oasis) oasis file with several libraries – how can I enable `-w ..` and `-warn-error +a` for each of them?

---

For reference purposes, the given oasis file starts like this:

```
OASISFormat: 0.4
Name:        re
Version:     1.5.0
Synopsis:    Pure OCaml regular expression library
Authors:     Jerome Vouillon, Thomas Gazagnaire, Anil Madhavapeddy
License:     LGPL-2.0 with OCaml linking exception
Plugins:     META (0.4), DevFiles (0.4)
AlphaFeatures: compiled_setup_ml
BuildTools: ocamlbuild

Library re
  Path:       lib
  InternalModules: Re_cset, Re_automata
  Modules: Re
  Findlibname: re
  BuildDepends: bytes

Library re_emacs
  Path: lib
  XMETADescription: Emacs-compatible regexps
  Modules: Re_emacs
  Findlibname: emacs
  FindlibParent: re
  BuildDepends: re
```

Answer (score 5):

At the top level in `_oasis`, add

```
AlphaFeatures: ocamlbuild_more_args
XOCamlbuildExtraArgs: "-cflags 'flags'"
```

`-cflags 'flags'` will get passed to `ocamlbuild`, which then passes `flags` to `ocamlc`. In this case, the flags are `-w +9+27+32 -warn-error +a`